# YUV to XYZ conversion

Tags: image, matlab, colors, transformation, yuv

I would like to convert 10 bit, bt.2020 YUV color image to XYZ color components. Are there anybody help me for this?

Also, is Y components in YUV and L component in Lab same?

Comment: No, it is not the same, it is only same for Constant Luminance. So, you first upsample chrome from 420 to 444 using top-left FIR (maybe a good one with Lancsoz 3 taps), then you convert Y'CbCr to R'G'B' using bt.2020 non constant, then you convert R'G'B' to RGB using PQ transfer, then you convert using the primaries of BT.2020 to XYZ using NPM from SMPTE RP 177

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.poynton.com/PDFs/coloureq.pdf) document, Y in `YUV` is same as Y in `CIE XYZ` space. However, L in `CIE LAB` space has a nonlinear relation with Y. You can check the relation [in the same document](http://www.poynton.com/PDFs/coloureq.pdf), equation 19.

So the short answer to your question is no. Also, for colorspace conversion, I prefer [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28790-colorspace-transformations/content/colorspace/colorspace.m) library.

Comment: This doesn't affect the answer but FYI, the YUV you linked to is the 1960 CIE YUV[1]. I think the asker might be talking about the more well known YUV used in color television[2]. The Y in the latter is not the same Y as CIEXYZ.

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIE_1960_color_space
[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I have recently come across the same problem and only found a hint of what needs to be done by accident (a reference in a google book search sample. P251 of "Digital Video and HD: Algorithms and Interfaces").

This is my understanding of what needs to be done, so it could be incorrect and/or incomplete:

Calculate the Normalised Primary Matrix (NPM) using SMPTE RP-177 section 3.3 in combination with the colour primaries (CIE 1931 chromaticity coordinates) of the colour space (e.g. Rec.709). There is a worked example in Annex B.1.

Convert the YUV (YCbCr) values to RGB using the matrix coefficients of the colour space.

Then apply the NPM to the RGB values to calculate the XYZ coordinates.

Comment: Actually, you got it in reverse. 177 talks about how matrix (from R'G'B' to YCbCr) is derived from 3 primaries and white point.